# Can I use Microsoft SyncToy to auto-backup my drives without me taking action?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, synctoy

Can I use Microsoft SyncToy to backup my drives without me taking action? I want to to back up often, like every 30 minutes.

Comment: You'll have to set it up, but afterwards it can be schedulde to run periodically by creating a scheduled task. See the SyncToy help file for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  I do this, but not every 30 min.  There is no compression.  But you know how synctoy works so if you want every folder pair or one one it's up to you. Start a windows task scheduler event turn through the menus and here are some tips:

In the Add arguments box, enter –R to run all of your syncs each time.

Alternately, if you’d only like to run one of your syncs, enter –R “your sync name”.  Make sure to enter the sync name inside quotes if it contains any spaces.

Comment: Totally new to the windows task scheduler, any idea how I would set this up? Thanks again :)

Comment: Found my answer here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25046/schedule-synctoy-to-run-automatically-with-task-scheduler-in-windows-7/